# DECIMAL type rounding extra decimals and not truncating mysql

Tags: mysql, database, types, decimal, rounding

DECIMAL type should represent 'Exact', but it's rounding the number, eg:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo`(p1 DECIMAL(5,2));

INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (587.487);

SELECT * FROM `foo`;
```

it stores `587.49` instead of `587.48` which is the 'exact' truncated value, how can I store the value in the correct way for decimal, which I need to be 'exact' not rounded

P.S: I'm using strict mode

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE `foo`(p1 DECIMAL(5,2));

INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (truncate(587.487,2));

SELECT * FROM `foo`;
```

Check [<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58575/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to know why Decimal is not working as 'Exact', i would need to truncate each field in case i don't know when it would exceed decimal parts, i know float and double should ROUND but why DECIMAL should too?

Comment: It's default behaviour of decimal datatype and It's truncate if decimal point value is greater than 2 as per our syntax given then don't worry for truncate value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact then input in the same format as `decimal( 5, 2 )` or truncate into 5 digits including fraction part.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select @n1:=587.487 n1 
    ->      , cast( substr( @n1, 1, 6 ) as decimal( 5, 2 ) ) s1
    ->      , @n2:=587 n2
    ->      , cast( substr( @n2, 1, 6 ) as decimal( 5, 2 ) ) s2
    ->      , @n3:=587 n3, substr( @n3, 1, 6 ) s3
    -> ;
+---------+--------+-----+--------+-----+------+
| n1      | s1     | n2  | s2     | n3  | s3   |
+---------+--------+-----+--------+-----+------+
| 587.487 | 587.48 | 587 | 587.00 | 587 | 587  |
+---------+--------+-----+--------+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Note** that you require to re-cast on whole numbers if you want output as decimal format.

But, `truncate` would be a better choice over `substr` as it fills decimal part with zeros if missing.

```
select truncate( 587.487, 2 ) t1, truncate ( 587.4, 2 ) t3;
+--------+--------+
| t1     | t3     |
+--------+--------+
| 587.48 | 587.40 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to know why Decimal is not working as 'Exact', i would need to truncate each field in case i don't know when it would exceed decimal parts, i know float and double should ROUND but why DECIMAL should too?